# Define 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I had the issue if I try to start my java spring application.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.michelecastriotta</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SimpleWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**web.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>Spring Secured Application</display-name>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <!-- ... -->

        <!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**webSecurityConfig.xml**

```xml
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login login-page='/login.html' default-target-url="/homepage.html" authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <b:bean id="encoder"
            class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
</b:beans>
```

This is the **SecSecurityConfig.java** class

```java
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:webSecurityConfig.xml" })
public class SecSecurityConfig{

    public SecSecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }


    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        // InMemoryUserDetailsManager (see below)
        UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withUsername("user2")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html",true)
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true");
        return http.getOrBuild();
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

the application have no error, but if I try to start the application I can see the following error:

```java
2024-03-01 15:36:13.383  INFO 16808 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.h.DefaultFilterChainValidator    : Checking whether login URL '/login.html' is accessible with your configuration
2024-03-01 15:36:13.682  WARN 16808 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [it/michelecastriotta/SimpleWebApp/Security/SecSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-03-01 15:36:13.687  INFO 16808 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-03-01 15:36:13.695  INFO 16808 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-01 15:36:13.790 ERROR 16808 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method filterChain in it.michelecastriotta.SimpleWebApp.Security.SecSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:26826', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What can I do to fix the issue?

**EDIT**
If I try to add in SecSecurityConfig class the following annotation @EnableWebSecurity
if I try to start the application I have this error:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [webSecurityConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot register alias 'springSecurityFilterChain' for name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Alias would override bean definition 'springSecurityFilterChain'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:417) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:196) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:203) ~[spring-beans-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_402]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:156) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:756) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:572) ~[spring-context-5.3.31.jar:5.3.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289) [spring-boot-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
```

Comment: In your configuration class SecSecurityConfig add this annotation: `@EnableWebSecurity`

Comment: I just edit my question, if I insert enableWebSecurity, I received other error.

Comment: You are mixing XML and Java configuration in one Spring Boot application. This is wrong. Just remove those XML files and stick with Java classes.

Comment: also you have defined a parent in your pom with spring v2.7 but then you have pulled in the 2.3 version of spring security? remove the version number from the spring security starter so that it gets its version automatically from the parent.